# Is there a way to record a livestream with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, http-live-streaming

I wanted to automate the video recording with Python. I started with my code and tried a simple .m3u8 file. But now I've found out that the .m3u8 file automatically update after a few seconds.

```
r = requests.get(url) m3u8_master = m3u8.loads(r.text)

playlist = m3u8.loads(r.text) playlist.data['segments'][0]['uri'] r = requests.get(url2 + playlist.data['segments'][0]['uri']) with open("test.ts", "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

.m3u8 file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:12634365
#EXTINF:10.0000,
20190221T021754-05-12634365.ts
#EXTINF:10.0000,
20190221T021754-05-12634366.ts
#EXTINF:10.0000,
20190221T021754-05-12634367.ts
#EXTINF:10.0000,
20190221T021754-05-12634368.ts
#EXTINF:10.0000,
20190221T021754-05-12634369.ts
#EXTINF:10.0000,
20190221T021754-05-12634370.ts
```

.m3u8 file some seconds later:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:12634366
#EXTINF:10.0000,
20190221T021754-05-12634366.ts
#EXTINF:10.0000,
20190221T021754-05-12634367.ts
#EXTINF:10.0000,
20190221T021754-05-12634368.ts
#EXTINF:10.0000,
20190221T021754-05-12634369.ts
#EXTINF:10.0000,
20190221T021754-05-12634370.ts
#EXTINF:10.0000,
20190221T021754-05-12634371.ts
```

I just want a python script that can record livestream like this without ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

The .m3u8 format just tells where to find the video files and in what order they come. It is the .ts files them self that contain the video and since you mention not using ffmpeg I would suggest running a loop to fetch all the files and save them. The nice thing about .ts files is that they can be combined into one file, so you can just append the last file to the next one as long as they are sequential. And then run a loop to fetch the next files as they are produced.
A good video for showing this is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bytnxnZFLeg he goes through how do do a static .m3u8 file video stream, but can easily be adopted to live video.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is by using vlc player, I know you wanted to do it with python but maybe some people have similar need.

1. Set the directory output in tools > preferences > files > record directory or filename
2. open network stream (ctrl+n)
3. once start playing hit record (playback > record)
4. let finish playback or stop, find the vlc file in the directory specified